# Ruby DSL: Strict Method Visibility Technique needed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, metaprogramming, activesupport

```
module Powers
 def outer_method name, &block
  puts "outer method works"
   yield 
  end 
 def inner_method name, &block
  puts "inner method works ONLY inside outer method"
  yield 
 end
end 
class Superman
 include Powers 
 def attack 
  outer_method "fly to moon" do 
   inner_method "take a dump" do 
    p "feels good and earth is safe"
   end
  end
  inner_method "take a dump" do 
   p "earth is doomed" 
  end 
 end 
Superman.new.attack
```

How to enforce that the inner_method can ONLY be called from the context inside outer_method and save the planet??

Comment: you cant, `send` gives access to all methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really can't understand why you need this. But what about this "hack"?

```
module Powers
  def outer_method(name, &block)
    puts 'outer method works'
    self.class.send :class_eval, <<-STR, __FILE__, __LINE__
      def inner_method(name, &block)
        puts 'inner method works ONLY inside outer method'
        yield
      end
    STR
    yield
  ensure
    self.class.send(:remove_method, :inner_method) if respond_to?(:inner_method)
  end
end

class Superman
  include Powers

  def attack
    outer_method 'fly to moon' do
      inner_method 'take a dump' do
        p 'feels good and earth is safe'
      end
    end
    inner_method 'take a dump' do
      p 'earth is doomed'
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Note, that this method is expensive and not flexible. But it shows a power of Ruby, heh.

Comment: noted and thanks, I would update this if I found a cleaner way. 

This is needed when you don't want to use dsl constructs out of context, this way you will be able to nest your dsl constructs in a pleasing way aesthetically

Answer (score 1):

Since you're including `Powers` within `Superman`, the `Powers` methods are treated as methods of the `Superman` class, so there is no access control that will prevent them from being accessible to any other method in `Superman`, including `inner_method`.

Comment: Sorry, I failed to note the `include Powers`. See updated answer.

Comment: Thats for the explanation, and the previous links. yet this doesn't fix the problem... whats the idea\hack\technique\pattern  we are missing that could make this actually work?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "make this actually work". If you make `Powers` a class and don't `include` it, then you can use the `protected` or `private` methods to prevent access to `inner_method` (modulo the `send` workaround).

Comment: noted, nevertheless I am more inclined to the use of modules over classes whenever possible.